# Javascript pixel manipulation of canvas, Blur filter not working

Tags: javascript, canvas, filter, pixel

Im currently working on a simple drawing board website in canvas.

http://webbox.cs.du.edu/~ansbashe/My_Art/myart.html

I want to blur the canvas with this javascript code (in a webworker).  The problem is that the returning data fill the canvas with the original picture and not the blurred image that I am expecting.  Is there anything I can do to get the outcome that I am looking for?

```
var  filter =   [   [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]];

var factor = 1/9; 
var bias = 0; 

var w = 890;
var h = 400;
function filts() {

    filt = 0;
    for(var x = 0; x < w;  x++)
    {
        for(var y = 0; y < h; y++)
        {
            var r = 0;
            var g = 0;
            var b = 0;
            var imgX = ((x - Math.floor(filter.length/2)+filterX + w) % w);
            var imgY = ((y - Math.floor(filter.length/2)+filterY + h)%h);

            for(var filterX = 0; filterX < filter.length; filterX++) {
                for(var filterY =0; filterY < filter.length; filterY++) {


                    r += imgData.data[imgX*4 + imgY * w * 4] * filter[filterY][filterX];
                    g += imgData.data[imgX*4 + imgY*w*4 + 1] * filter[filterY][filterX];
                    b += imgData.data[imgX*4 + imgY*w*4 + 2] * filter[filterY][filterX];

                }
            }
            var index = (x + (y * w)) * 4;
            retData.data[imgX*4 + imgY*w*4] = Math.min(Math.max(Math.floor(factor *r + bias),0),255);
            retData.data[imgX*4 + imgY*w*4 + 1] = Math.min(Math.max(Math.floor(factor *g + bias),0),255);
            retData.data[imgX*4 + imgY*w*4 + 2] = Math.min(Math.max(Math.floor(factor *b + bias),0),255);
            retData.data[imgX*4 + imgY*w*4 + 3] = imgData.data[imgX*4 + imgY*w*4 + 3];

        }
    }
    postMessage({img: retData});
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to offset the co-ordinates that you are reading from inside your filter loop, or else you will be reading from the same pixel each time (imgX, imgY):

```
for(var filterX = 0; filterX < filter.length; filterX++) {
    var filterImgX = (imgX + filterX) % w;
    for(var filterY =0; filterY < filter.length; filterY++) {            
        var filterImgY = (imgY + filterY) % h;

        r += imgData.data[filterImgX*4 + filterImgY * w * 4] * filter[filterY][filterX];
        g += imgData.data[filterImgX*4 + filterImgY*w*4 + 1] * filter[filterY][filterX];
        b += imgData.data[filterImgX*4 + filterImgY*w*4 + 2] * filter[filterY][filterX];

    }
}
```